# what is the concept of throttling in scheduler?

Tags: linux, kernel

I am studying the scheduler code of linux kernel. in cfs_rq throttled, throttled_clock, throttled_count etc are used. can anyone explain the concept behind this.

I have searched it on internet but couldn't found any answer.

Answer (score 1):

i think its used when we forcefully move the things to another cpu from one. in that case we just throttle the tasks on one cpu

Comment: How?? can you explain with some snapshot with some example?? it would be nice if you can add some reference for detailed explanation. Thanks.